# Conexión a Multiple Bases de Datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, dominio

**CONTEXTO**

Servidor en el cual se tienen tres subdominios, con tres Bases de datos iguales, obviamente con sus claves y usuarios diferentes. Se decidió que se habría que crear un subdominio para cada empresa, con el fin de que fuese mas personal el uso del sistema y no hubiese cantidad de datos de diferentes empresas en una sola BD.

**PROBLEMA**

Requiero acceder a los datos desde mi dominio principal *www.dominio.com* a cada una de las bases de datos de mis subdominios.

**CODIGO PLANTEADO**

```
<?php
  $dominio    = 'xxxxxxxx';
  $usuarioDB  = 'yyyyyyyy';
  $claveUser  = 'zzzzzzzz';
  $nameBD     = 'xx-yy-zz';


  $mysqli = new mysqli($dominio, $usuarioDB, $claveUser, $nameBD);
  if($mysqli->connect_error):
  {
    echo "Error al tratar de conectarse con MySql debido al error ".$mysqli->connect_error;
  }
  endif;
?>
```

Teniendo en cuenta esto, desde una BD de mi dominio principal debo de cargar los datos de acceso para el SuperUsuario por asi decirlo, en donde tambien tengo que almacenar cada uno de los datos de conexion de las BD.

Y posteriormente cargar los datos correspondientes dentro de la plataforma.

**PREGUNTAS**

1. Es posible cargar una BD dentro de otra BD?
2. ¿Qué tan viable sería esta solución?
3. si no, ¿cuál sería otra opcion para solucionar lo que planteo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, o no exactamente tendrías que exportar e importar lo cual obviamente pierde la consistencia de datos entre las bases.
2. Pues lo que estas haciendo es una mala administración, por que a mi opinión personal, deberia ser una base y que los schemas tuvieran el prefijo del subdominio.

En vez de

```
Subdominio A        Subdominio B      Subdominio C
 |-- Base A          |-- Base B        |-- Base C
```

Podría ser

```
 Base
   |-- SubdominioA_Base   |-- SubdominioB_Base    |-- SubdominioC_Base
```

Así ya solo tendrías tu *superUser* y podrías administrar todo.

3. Bueno creo que esa la puse en la 2 :P Saludos y suerte